# Invisible and not selectable objects in cells scrolling down a long static table view in IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, interface-builder, invisible, adaptive-layout

Actually I'm using XCode 7 and I'm trying to lay out a static table view in IB. I have "sizes classes" ticked (adaptive layout) and the table view is taller than the default square scene of 600x600 points. I can work fine with the cells in the top 600 points of the scene, that is its height.
When I scroll down the height of the scene, I can't select table cells by clicking on them in the scene (but I can in the outline). When I drag any object (e.g. a label) onto one of these cells, it goes into the view outside the cell and when I put the object inside the cell by dragging it onto that cell in the outline, I can't see it on the scene neither move it  by dragging (it's like it was behind the cell's content view). May anybody help me?
It's a very weird behavior... I'm getting crazy!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if is the same problem, but I had problems editing statics cells when there are many. So in the size inspector of the view controller I set the simulated size to "freeform" and increase the height to unreasonable levels (2000), and then I can access the bottom cells.

Here a screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Yes, I have exactly the same problem.